# What does this mean: "warning: comparison between 'enum A<B>' and 'enum A<B>'"?

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, compiler-warnings

I added following at line 42 of proto.h:

```
typedef boost::make_unsigned<off_t>::type uoff_t;
```

And now I get this verbose and confusing warning from gcc complaining about comparing an enum to the same enum type:

```
In file included from proto.cpp:12:
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_unsigned.hpp: In instantiation of 'boost::detail::is_ununsigned_helper<long int>':
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_unsigned.hpp:73:   instantiated from 'boost::detail::is_unsigned_imp<long int>'
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_unsigned.hpp:123:   instantiated from 'boost::is_unsigned<long int>'
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/make_unsigned.hpp:110:   instantiated from 'boost::detail::make_unsigned_imp<long int>'
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/make_unsigned.hpp:130:   instantiated from 'boost::make_unsigned<long int>'
proto.h:42:   instantiated from here
/usr/local/include/boost/type_traits/is_unsigned.hpp:40: warning: comparison between 'enum boost::detail::is_unsigned_values<long int>::<anonymous>' and 'enum boost::detail::is_unsigned_values<long int>::<anonymous>'
```

Can anyone decipher this?

Comment: What version of Boost are you using?

Comment: @GMan: Maybe he has not. That boost may be the one preinstalled in his environment.

Comment: @WilliamKF: Look at `/usr/local/include/boost/version.hpp`. GCC version will help as well.

Comment: @usta Boost is v1.43.0 (major.minor.patchLevel)

Comment: @usta g++ (GCC) 4.2.1 20070719  [FreeBSD]

Comment: @WilliamKF: Thanks for the info. So that is FreeBSD with gcc 4.2.1 and Boost 1.43.0. Exactly a configuration I have, so can try out this on my side and see if the behavior is the same.

Comment: @WilliamKF: Tried myself on FreeBSD, Boost 1.43 with both gcc 4.2.1 and 4.5.0, but don't get a warning out of the box. I do get this exact warning if I manually `#define BOOST_NO_INCLASS_MEMBER_INITIALIZATION` before `#include <boost/type_traits/make_unsigned.hpp>`, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what happens

`BOOST_NO_INCLASS_MEMBER_INITIALIZATION` gets defined in Boost.Config (not sure why it would for gcc, but I'll leave that alone for the moment). Thus,

```
BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(no_cv_t, minus_one = (static_cast<no_cv_t>(-1)));
BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(no_cv_t, zero = (static_cast<no_cv_t>(0)));
```

declarations in `boost::detail::is_unsigned_values` get expanded to

```
enum { minus_one = (static_cast<no_cv_t>(-1)) };
enum { zero = (static_cast<no_cv_t>(0)) };
```

then these two enumerators of unnamed but *different* enumerations get compared in `boost::detail::is_ununsigned_helper`. Hence the warning, which wouldn't have happened if `BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT()` were expanded to `static const no_cv_t blah blah...`.

There are two questions left to be answered:

-> Why does `BOOST_NO_INCLASS_MEMBER_INITIALIZATION` get defined in your case?

-> If that macro does get defined, such a warning (comparison of enumerators of different enums) can be produced. It's harmless here, yet it might be nice to be prevented in Boost. Is that worth it?

Note: I used Boost 1.43's code for reference.